# Problem with getting Id for the transient object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am having two entity classes Entity1 and Entity2.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "users" )
public class Entity1{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table( name = "all" )
public class Entity2{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private Entity1 entity;

    //getters and setters
}
```

now i am saving the whole entity in one save request. so that time my request will be something like below.

```
{
 entity1:{"name": ""XYZ"},
 entity2:{"entity1": {"name": "XYZ"}}
}
```

while saving this entity 1 will generate one id. after that while accessing the entity1 which is present inside the entity2, entity2.getID() coming as null. what should i do to get the id?

Comment: *now i am saving the whole entity in one save request* can you provide code on that? Even after reading your question multiple times I still don't understand what you are asking, please try to clarify/provide more information

Comment: can you show the code tha do the "saving"